# How to add External data source into MySQL?

Tags: mysql, odbc, datasource, filemaker

I have two database. One is FileMaker database and another one is mysql. I want to use this database in mysql.I created odbc data base connection so that I can sync both database e.g when I maker changes in mysql database then FileMaker database should also be updated. Is this thing possible in mysql? If no then in which open source database this thing is supported?

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do that with FileMaker would be to hook the MySQL database up to FileMaker via [External SQL Sources](http://www.filemaker.com/support/technologies/sql.html) (ESS).

You can create layouts in FileMaker that display the actual MySQL data, and the MySQL can be used in FileMaker scripts, calculations, etc. just like any other FileMaker data.

You can choose to simply build layouts that are based on MySQL tables, or you can create scripts in FileMaker to copy data from MySQL based layouts to actual FileMaker based layouts.